# How prepareForSegue works?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am curious about this method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
```

I find this method in UIViewController.h, and it's a regular method.
I check it, it is not a delegate method (it is not a protocol).

Because UITableViewController extends from UIViewController, we can use this method in our custom class for any table views.

Strangely, this method behaves like a delegate, it fires without any calls.
It fires when the view is going to do a transition.

As far as I know, this behaviour only exist in delegation.

How can a UIViewController calls prepareForSegue method in it's child class?

Answer (score 3):

`prepareForSegue` is a method that is called as and when a transition is going to occur between ViewControllers. So, whenever a segue is made, this method will be called mandatorily. Now if your main View has a subclassed View and you want to perform a Segue from it, you can do it using the following function.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

In this case, this method will invoke a transition with the specified identifier which corresponds to a segue. And whenever this method is called, `prepareForSegue` is called immediately after this, after which transition occurs.

For information, it is better to connect segue between ViewControllers rather than creating segue directly from Controls in the view. As sometimes, some conditions need to be checked before performing a Segue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you do trigger a segue straight from a control you can use shouldPerformSegue to determine if the segue should proceed, but if you want to trigger different segues from the same control depending upon conditions then performSegueWithIdentifier is the way to do it.

Comment: It's not what I'm asking for.
I mean, there's no way the super class (UIViewController) can call my custom child class prepareForSegue method.
Because super class cannot call it's child class method.

Answer (score 1):

Like many other methods of `UIViewController`, your subclass can override the default behavior of many `UIViewController` methods. A couple of examples include `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: yes, I override it, but how can it trigger automatically?
UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController. The super class (UIViewController) cannot call it's child class method. How can the overrided method in UITableViewController run?